# Class Field Default Values

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I'm trying to understand [Public class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields), and I don't think this is possible, but I wanted to ask anyway.  What I'm looking for is to define the class field's default, but if it's passed into my constructor, then that value is used.

In the example below, I would expect `child.Values` to be `[1, 2]`, but instead, I get `[]`.  Is there any way to treat the class field value as a default value?

```js
class Parent {
  constructor(args) {
    this.set(args);
  }

  set(field, value) {
    for (const key in field) {
      Reflect.set(this, key, field[key]);
    }
    console.log('Parent after setting:', this.Values)
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  // If I remove this, then my use case works, but I want a default value
  Values = [];
}

var child = new Child({
  Values: [1, 2]
})

console.log('Child getting:', child.Values)
```

Comment: It is very unclear what you want exactly. What is the purpose of using class inheritance here? The `Parent` class is not providing any value except for a constructor that takes the args and turns it into member properties. This is a use of class inheritance that goes against its purpose. How about explaining why you are doing what you are doing?

Comment: I mean, I'm going to have a `Parent` class that other classes inherit from.  The `Parent` class has methods/properties on it that I'll need in sub-classes.  Is this not what class inheritance is meant for?

Answer (score 0):

Of course I figured out a way shortly after posting.  There is a way of doing this if I remove the `this.set(args)` from `Parent`'s constructor and add it in `Child`'s constructor.  It's not ideal, as I'd like Parent to handle this, but it at least addresses the issue.

```js
class Parent {
  set(field, value) {
    for (const key in field) {
      Reflect.set(this, key, field[key]);
    }
    console.log('Parent after setting:', this.Values)
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  // If I remove this, then my use case works, but I want a default value
  Values = [];
  
  constructor(args) {
    super(args);
    this.set(args);
  }
}

var child = new Child({
  Values: [1, 2]
})

console.log('Child getting:', child.Values)
```

Comment: I also find it the only working way of doing that. In your question, because your first parent fields are initialized, then you change the Values field, only then the child Values field is initialized with an empty array overriding the value that's been set in the parent.

Comment: To test when field are initialized you use this approach: `class Parent {
  parentField = (()=> console.log('parent field init :)'))();
}`

Comment: "*It's not ideal, as I'd like Parent to handle this*" - why would the parent handle initialising the child's properties?

Comment: @Bergi valid question, but I was hoping to have a generic `set` method that didn't have to be called in each sub-class, which would abstract that boilerplate code.  In short, I'm lazy and wanted to DRY up my code.

Comment: Tbh, `this.values = args.values ?? [];` would be even less boilerplate code :-) Btw, you can replace `this.set(args)` by `Object.assign(this, args);`, you don't even need a `Parent` class. (If that was your only reason to introduce the base class - it's not quite clear from the example)